# Print only once in nested loop

Tags: python, loops, break, vpython

I am modeling a particle moving through different layers, and once it moves through the layer I want it to print a few things. My problem is the particle can move back into the previous layer and come out again, which triggers it to print again, I do not want this.

```
while math.sqrt((pho.pos.x)*(pho.pos.x)+(pho.pos.y)*(pho.pos.y)+(pho.pos.z)*(pho.pos.z))<10:
    x=random.uniform(-j,j)
    y=random.uniform(-j,j)
    z=random.uniform(-j,j)
    step=(x,y,z)
    t=t+dt
    pho.pos=pho.pos+step
    print 'Step Number', t
    rate(speed)
    d=math.sqrt((pho.pos.x)*(pho.pos.x)+(pho.pos.y)*(pho.pos.y)+(pho.pos.z)*(pho.pos.z))
    '''if d>10:
        print pho.pos 
        print d 
        print 'Out of Layer 1 in',t,'steps!'
        break
    else:
        pass'''
d=math.sqrt((pho.pos.x)*(pho.pos.x)+(pho.pos.y)*(pho.pos.y)+(pho.pos.z)*(pho.pos.z))
print pho.pos
print d
print 'Out of Layer 1 in',t,'steps!'
```

The part I don't want repeating is the last three print statements, I have tried break statements but this code is a nested loop, and when it gets re-looped it starts over before the break.

Answer (score 0):

On whatever class `pho` is, make a property called `printed` or something and initialize it to `False`. Then, set it to True when printing for the first time, and say

```
if d > 10 and not pho.printed
```

instead of just `if d > 10`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Your code I *think* was all supposed to be part of the while loop. If not, move the `out_of_layer` to before the next outer loop.

```
out_of_layer = False  

while math.sqrt((pho.pos.x)*(pho.pos.x)+(pho.pos.y)*(pho.pos.y)+(pho.pos.z)*(pho.pos.z))<10:
    x=random.uniform(-j,j)

    ... blah blah stuff you already know about ...

    d=math.sqrt((pho.pos.x)*(pho.pos.x)+(pho.pos.y)*(pho.pos.y)+(pho.pos.z)*(pho.pos.z))
    if not out_of_layer:
        print pho.pos
        print d
        print 'Out of Layer 1 in',t,'steps!'
        out_of_layer = True
```